# javascript error: cannot read properties of null (reading 'window')

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using javascript in my aspx page. code below:-

```
    function Refresh()
    {
       var url=opener.window.location.href;
       opener.window.RefreshTabContent();
    }
```

I am opening a new tab from a link, this code I have written in a new tab, that is opened `opener.window.RefreshTabContent();`
refreshes the previous tab, while

`var url=opener.window.location.href;` assigns the URL to the previous tab.

In the above code I am getting error: **cannot read properties of null (reading 'window')**
Please help where I am making error.
Thanks

Comment: I voted to close this question due to the lack of information. What is `opener` and where does it come from?

Comment: Give more details. What you want to do?

Comment: Added more explaination

Comment: clearly `opener` is `null` - which occurs if the page has not been opened by another page as described in the documentation for [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener)- since we don't know how the page you have an issue has been opened, you'll need to figure it out for yourself I guess